# EventSystem first selected not highlighting

Tags: unity, gui, bug

I'm trying to make a menu and encountered this problem.

```
protected static EventSystem eventSystem
{
    get { return GameObject.Find("EventSystem").GetComponent<EventSystem>(); }
}

public static void ButtonNavigation(List<GameObject> _listButton, int firstSelected)
{
    eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(_listButton[firstSelected]);
    print(eventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject);
}
```

[image: Problem]

But when I print out the currentSelectedGameobject it clearly says that "Status" is selected but how come it's not highlighted?

I've read some article on using Co-routines but is it really necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject` to null first before setting it to anything.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the color of it to something bright lol

Comment: Try setting the normal colour to black or something dark? Maybe you'll see a differnece.

Comment: it's still the same

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Apparently, that worked. Can you explain why that is?

Comment: It just does I guess? I can't find any documentation that states why it is like that but I just found some old questions on other answer sites that said that doing that will work.